# How to combine Data types

Tags: sql

I want to Combine Height and Height-units together but they are formatted in different data types

I've tried to add them them together, but since they are listed as different data types, I get a completely different result.

```
SELECT rclm_dem.HEIGHT + rclm_dem.HEIGHT_UNIT,
```

Results is instead of getting say '56 inches' I get something like '142534'

Height Unit also has codes (1 for inches & 2 for centimeters)

Height Unit is classified as LONG and Height is classified as Decimal

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results in a text table format also helps.

Comment: You will need to convert the unit codes to strings ("inches" or "centimeters") using a lookup table or a `CASE` statement, and then convert the numeric height value to character data and finally concatenate (not add) the numeric value and the unit string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL, CONVERT, CAST Data Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790948/sql-convert-cast-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT option might give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,rclm_dem.HEIGHT) + CONVERT(nvarchar,rclm_dem.HEIGHT_UNIT)
```

With the CAST option

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,convert(varchar, cast(56.787534 as money)))
```

Comment: So I tried the convert option and the result is a table that looks like this           Column_name and underneath its gives me numbers such as '56.787534'

Comment: You can use incorporate the CAST option, see edited answer